# settings.cpython-39 как редактировать файл?

Tags: python

учусь работать с Django. В список installed apps хотел добавить еще один пункт, открыл password_generator__ pycache __\settings.cpython-39 и внутри файла обнаружил вот такой код

'''�a�b4dlmZ ee��� jjZdZdZg Z  g d�Z
g d�ZdZdg dd g d
�i d�gZ
dZd'''

Знаю, что интерпретатор сначала упрощает, и потом сохраняет прогу в папку __ pycache __, но с таким видом сталкиваюсь впервые. Скажите, как я могу в этом случае привести файл к нормальному виду Allowed hosts = ...  Installed apps = ... Middleware = ... и работать с ним дальше? Проблема в коде или в настройке среды?
Пишу сейчас на pycharm

Открыл в Sublime, показывает: 6c70 6174 7465 726e 733a 2020 7061 7468
2827 626c 6f67 2f27 2c20 696e 636c 7564
08da 075f 5f64 6f63 5f5f 5a0e 646a 616e
676f 2e63 6f6e 7472 6962 7202 0000 00da и так далее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад любому ответу\совету :)

Comment: Скомпилированные файлы не предназначены для редактирования

Comment: И вообще зачем вы в папку `__pycache__` полезли

Comment: Там то же самое содержимое по смыслу, что и в исходных settings.py и __init__.py из которых они и компилировались. Вот их и смотрите. Если только не хотите изучить как формируется байт-код и что там за команды, в чем я сильно сомневаюсь.

Comment: Если сильно нужно, то можно попытаться декомпилировать байткод, например см. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608342/4752653 . Но т.к. у вас есть исходники, то в этом нет особого смысла.

Comment: всем большое спасибо! буду разбираться в исходниках